# Help identifying audio equipment

Tags: audio-recording

I found this image on the web and I was trying to identify different components in it. Could anyone help?

[image]

This is most likely equipment for a live use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a bunch of wireless units.  Hard to tell from the resolution if they are wireless transmitters (for wireless monitors) or wireless receivers (for microphones).  My guess would be receivers.  In particular, they appear to be [Audio-Technica 3000 series wireless receivers](http://www.audio-technica.com/cms/wls_systems/7ee89d5bb13ceadd/index.html).

Below them I'm not sure what the white unit is, but possibly a recorder based on the layout of the controls. (The black lines are generally protection around the record button.)

Below that appears to be either a patch bay or an output hookup for the feeds coming from the receivers.

The unit sitting on top of the rack is an effects unit and the unit way at the bottom and hidden behind appears to be an older receiver which I vaguely recognize but can't remember the model of.

Comment: I guess that is a recorder too. A solid state one- you see the spots for the safety screws on the card reader gate and the 1/4" monitoring on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Those are Triax patch points at the bottom. There are 8 male connectors in two groups in the first row, and 4 female connectors centered in the second row. The female connections receive signal from the camera and feed it to camera control units (CCU's) in a control room somewhere. The male ends are extension points coming from locations around the building where cameras would be deployed.

The male ends are marked 'House cable' and are probably split between two theaters or auditoriums. My bet is that this facility runs four cameras at a time, so they patch any 4 of the house cables to the control room.

The triax carries bi-directional signals between the base station and the camera. Signals include camera pictures, intercom, return video, audio, teleprompter and control data.